# c# Streaming downgraded-quality video over HTTP

Tags: c#, .net, video-streaming, servicestack

I have very large high quality videos that I need to stream over HTTP (for mobile devices). It is not possible to use ffmpeg to create a "streaming" version of the video.

I must also still support HTTP's seek/begin feature so that the user may skip ahead in the video.

I am using ServiceStack (not IIS).

Are there any options available out there?

I have access to the server, so any third party services are acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've recently added **Partial Content support** both in [directly serving Static files](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/PartialContentResultTests.cs#L107) as well as [via a Web Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/PartialContentResultTests.cs#L120). This will be available in [v3.9.44 release of ServiceStack](https://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/) on NuGet which is planned for this weekend (you can build [ServiceStack from the repo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack) if you need it before then).

Partial Content support will be automatically enabled where it will be available to seek/stream any static file (served through ServiceStack) as well as any Service that:

returns a file:

```
return new HttpResult(new FileInfo(filePath), request.MimeType);
```

returns bytes:

```
return new HttpResult(byteArray, "audio/mpeg");
```

returns a stream:

```
return new HttpResult(memoryStream, "audio/mpeg");
```

returns a raw string:

```
return new HttpResult(customText, "text/plain");
```

To disable Partial Content support set:

```
Config.AllowPartialResponses = false;
```

Comment: Beautiful! Any suggestions on the compressed version of the videos?

Comment: Nope we just enable the transport of data, the compression is an application-level concern which I imagine would already be in the compressed stream/bytes that's being returned, which is already understood/expected by the client.

Comment: I'm still a bit shocked that adding video support to my API "just worked" ... copy/paste my image service, adjust a few things, and voila.  Awesome.